# В чем смысл проверки instance instanceof?

Tags: javascript

Встретил вот такую конструкцию:

```
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
   if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
      throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
   }
}
```

Подскажите для чего может понадобиться такая вот проверка?

Answer (score 1):

Если переменная `instance` не является экземпляром класса `Constructor`, то функция выдаст ошибку. По всей видимости (судя из сообщения об ошибке) предполагается что `instance` является функцией, которая проходит проверку (на наличие у экземпляра нужного метода). Хотя точно сказать сложно, не зная, что из себя представляет этот Constructor.

Comment: а зачем нижнее подчеркивание  тут ___classCallCheck__ ??

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, [Защищённые свойства](https://learn.javascript.ru/functional-inheritance#%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Comment: спасибо держи плюсик

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, если ты мне, то не я писал ответ))

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный упс ))))техническая ошибка ))))